# Boolean comparison is not working in if condition angular ionic

Tags: angular, ionic4

`carSeat` is checkbox input which value can be `true` or `false`, I checked the value of it using `console.log` and the it's showing the correct value, but it will not go into the if conditions.

```
if (this.carSeat == true) {
  this.YesOrNo = "Yes";
  if (this.typeCar == "Sedan") {
    console.log(` if condition : ${this.carSeat} `);
    this.Subtotal =
      this.sedanHourlyRate * this.hours +
      this.sedanFlatRate * this.days +
      this.carSeatHorlyFlatRate * this.hours +
      this.carSeatDailyFlatRate * this.days;
    this.SalesTax = (this.Subtotal * 13) / 100;
    this.total = this.Subtotal + this.SalesTax;
  }
  if (this.typeCar == "SUV") {
    this.Subtotal =
      this.suvHourlyRate * this.hours +
      this.suvFlatRate * this.days +
      this.carSeatHorlyFlatRate * this.hours +
      this.carSeatDailyFlatRate * this.days;
    this.SalesTax = (this.Subtotal * 13) / 100;
    this.total = this.Subtotal + this.SalesTax;
  }
}
if (this.carSeat == false) {
  this.YesOrNo = "No";
  if (this.typeCar == "Sedan") {
    this.Subtotal =
      this.sedanHourlyRate * this.hours + this.sedanFlatRate * this.days;
    this.SalesTax = (this.Subtotal * 13) / 100;
    this.total = this.Subtotal + this.SalesTax;
  }
  if (this.typeCar == "SUV") {
    this.Subtotal =
      this.suvHourlyRate * this.hours + this.suvFlatRate * this.days;
    this.SalesTax = (this.Subtotal * 13) / 100;
    this.total = this.Subtotal + this.SalesTax;
  }
}
```

[image]

I've tried `===` instead of `==` and still it's not entering into if condition.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share the state. The code looks like it should run correctly, but there might be a type mismatch

Comment: Hey have you tried my recommendation ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that value of bool is string

try `this.carSeat == 'true'`